# Show an server answer in a PDF form

Tags: forms, perl, pdf, cgi

I have a PDF form that submits the information to an Apache server with a CGI script written in Perl:

```
var doc = event.target;

var x = doc.submitForm({
        cURL: "http:",
        cSubmitAs: "XML" 
        });
```

The CGI is capable of reading the information and saving it in a file, but I want to resubmit a reference code to the `x` variable in the PDF and then have the PDF show it in a box. I use this in the CGI script:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "$i";
```

but it’s opening a new PDF that shows the content of the variable `$i`.

I don’t know if the problem is the PDF code that specifies in another way the reading of the variable or if it is the CGI script that sends the value in a wrong way.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

A form submit in PDF works just like a form submit in HTML. You send a request to the server and the server answers with a new page, in your case, the original page that was in PDF format was replaced by a new page of type "text/html" (which is odd, because you have no intention to send HTML to the browser).

It seems like you don't want to submit a form, but you want to submit data, and get a response in the same page. This is possible in HTML, but quite difficult to achieve in PDF. I've written a book about PDF and this is an excerpt that more or less meets your requirement: http://bit.ly/gl1Urw

In this example, I embed JavaScript in the PDF that is able to send a message the the JavaScript in an HTML page that embeds the PDF (and vice-versa). This way, you don't submit the data from the PDF to the server, but you pass it to the HTML page. In the HTML you can set up a communication with a server, and send the response to the PDF.

If that's not an option for you (for instance because you can't change the PDF that submits the data), you shouldn't respond with "text/html" content. Instead you should respond with a new PDF file that is identical to the original form, except for some fields you've filled out on the server-side.

Update: your question was based on assumptions that are wrong, you may want to edit it.